# Querying database multiple time simultaneously from IOS app causing crash

Tags: ios, mysql, swift, database

I am using MySqlDriver to access a relational database directly from my iOS app. But if I use multiple queries simultaneously it's causing the driver to crash.
the driver is in the following library: 
https://github.com/mcorega/MySqlSwiftNative

the code I am using is:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let con = MySQL.Connection()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let db_name = "database"

        do{
            try con.open("localhost", user: "root", passwd: "1234")
            try con.use(db_name)
        }
        catch (let e) {
            print(e)
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    @IBAction func onClickButton(sender: UIButton!){
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
            print("gone")
            let select_stmt = try? self.con.prepare("query")
                    let stRes = try? select_stmt!.query([])
                    if let rr = try? stRes!.readAllRows() {
                        print(rr)
                        if rr!.count > 0{
            //                completion(true, (rr.first!))
                        }else{
            //                completion(true, [[String: Any]]())
                        }
                    }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you know if the driver  supports it? If you get an error then you should include it as part of your question. The project hasn't been updated for 2 years, judging by questions here on SO I believe [SQLite.swift](https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift) is more commonly used and might therefore be easier to get help with when you run into an issue. I have no idea if it is better but at least the github project seems to be more active.

Answer (score 0):

I have update your code. Please check and let me know is it work for you or not.

```
@IBAction func onClickButton(sender: UIButton!){
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
    print("Success")
        let select_stmt = try? self.con.prepare("query")
        let stRes = try? select_stmt!.query([])
        if let rr = try? stRes!.readAllRows() {
           print(rr)
           if rr!.count > 0{
        //                completion(true, (rr.first!))
                   }else{
        //                completion(true, [[String: Any]]())
                    }
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://www.raywenderlich.com/5817-background-modes-tutorial-getting-started

It may be help you

Answer (score 0):

I built a library on top of SQLite that handles all of this. It’s called [SundeedQLite](https://github.com/noursandid/SundeedQLite)

When working with databases, you should know one thing, you can not access it asynchronously.

With that said, your onClickButton can be clicked two times in a fast way, enough that the first operation is not done, so it will cause problems.

That’s why it is better to make sure that all database accesses should be synchronous.

You should try to put the queries in a queue and pop them and process them one by one whenever the database is not processing anything.

Or try my library because these problems are already handled.